# Bootstrap Order Cards From Top to Bottom?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

When using Bootstrap Cards layout, the cards are ordered by default from left to right (i.e. imagine 9 data sets in an array, these are orderd as 1, 2, 3 in Column 1, then 4, 5, 6 in Column 2, then 7, 8, 9 in Column 3) rather than top to bottom. I.e I would expect that items 1, 2, 3 would be in Row 1, items 4, 5, 6 would be in Row 2 and then items 7, 8, 9 would be in Row 3.

I can't seem to find any way of customising this looking through the Bootstrap guides and online.

Has anyone found a way of doing this?

Comment: Bootstrap4. Bootstrap3 doesn't have Cards.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Alex Devero blog post](http://blog.alexdevero.com/mastering-card-design-with-bootstrap-4/), you can simply use the `row` class. Here is a full example from this blog post :

```
<div class="container m-t-md">
 <!-- First row -->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   <!-- Card -->
   <article class="card animated fadeInLeft">
    <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg" alt="Deer in nature" />
    <div class="card-block">
     <h4 class="card-title">Animal Farm</h4>
     <h6 class="text-muted">George Orwell</h6>
     <p class="card-text">Tired of their servitude to man, a group of farm animals revolt and establish their own society, only to be betrayed into worse servitude by their leaders, the pigs. This satire addresses the communist philosophy the Soviet Union.</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
    </div>
   </article><!-- .end Card -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
  <!-- Card -->
  <article class="card animated fadeInUp">
   <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Life After Life</h4>
    <h6 class="text-muted">Kate Atkinson</h6>
   </div>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/SYC0YBA37V.jpg" alt="Leaf on the street" />
   <div class="card-block">
    <p class="card-text">On a cold and snowy night, Ursula Todd is born, the 3rd child of a wealthy banker and his wife. She dies before she can draw her first breath. On that same cold and snowy night, lets out a lusty wail.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-block text-center">
    <div class="btn-group hidden-sm-down hidden-md-down" role="group" aria-label="Card buttons">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save for later</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical hidden-lg-up" role="group" aria-label="Card buttons">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save for later</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </article><!-- .end Card -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
  <!-- Card -->
  <article class="card animated fadeInRight">
   <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Wind, Sand and Stars</h4>
    <h6 class="text-muted">Antoine de Saint-Exupéry</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Story that captures the grandeur, danger, and isolation of flight. Its exciting account of air adventure, combined with lyrical prose and the spirit of a philosopher, makes it one of the most popular works ever written.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-block text-center">
    <div class="btn-group hidden-sm-down hidden-md-down" role="group" aria-label="Card buttons">
     <a href="#" class="card-link">Read more</a>
     <a href="#" class="card-link">Save for later</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical hidden-lg-up" role="group" aria-label="Card buttons">
     <a href="#" class="card-link">Read more</a><br />
     <a href="#" class="card-link">Save for later</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <img class="card-img-bottom img-responsive" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/8SALDQRRZX.jpg" alt="White sand" />
  </article><!-- .end Card -->
 </div>
 </div><!-- .end First row -->
 <!-- Second row -->
 <div class="row m-t-md">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   <!-- Card -->
   <article class="card card-inverse animated fadeInLeft">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg" alt="Deer in nature" />
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
     <h4 class="card-title">Animal Farm</h4>
     <h6 class="text-muted">George Orwell</h6>
     <p class="card-text">Tired of their servitude to man, a group of farm animals revolt and establish their own society...</p>
    </div>
   </article><!-- .end Card -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   <!-- Card -->
   <article class="card card-inverse animated fadeInDown">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/SYC0YBA37V.jpg" alt="Leaf on the street" />
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
     <h4 class="card-title">Life After Life</h4>
     <h6 class="text-muted">Kate Atkinson</h6>
     <p class="card-text">On a cold and snowy night, Ursula Todd is born, the 3rd child of a wealthy banker and his wife. She die...</p>
    </div>
   </article><!-- .end Card -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   <!-- Card -->
   <article class="card card-inverse animated fadeInRight">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/8SALDQRRZX.jpg" alt="White sand" />
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
     <h4 class="card-title">Wind, Sand and Stars</h4>
     <h6 class="text-muted">Antoine de Saint-Exupéry</h6>
     <p class="card-text">Story that captures the grandeur, danger, and isolation of flight. Its exciting account of air adventure...</p>
    </div>
   </article><!-- .end Card -->
  </div>
 </div><!-- .end Second row -->
</div>
```